# Ember/Handlebars: compare variable with string

Tags: if-statement, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to display some block depending on the current views variable in comparison to some string:

**PSEUDO** code is:

```
{{#if view.someVariable "desiredValue"}}
    Hurray desiredValue exists in this  view!
{{else}}
    Sorry, doesn't match...
{{/if}}
```

Of course it doesn't work as `if` statement allows only one param. I tried with custom `registerHelper` of Handlebars, but it doesn't resolve the `view.someVariable`, instead uses it as a string (although `view.someVariable` is defined and has value).

Finally I also tried with Handlebar's `registerBoundHelper` - it resolves the params BUT doesn't support Handlebar's blocks, what's more tries to resolve the string as an object, so fail again. Pure madness!

My views are very dynamical they depends on many factors also from backend and approach from the pseudo code would be perfect for resolving it. Is there any way to do that?

**Edit:** 
There is a sample of what I want ... http://jsfiddle.net/biesior/dMS2d/ looks quite trivial...

`[if]` statement inside the `each` is pseudo code of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare a computed property, something like `isDesired` on your view, which would compare `someVariable` to your string:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  // ...stuff...
  isDesired: Ember.computed.equal('someVariable', 'desiredValue')
});
```

And have a simple conditional in the template:

```
{{#if view.isDesired}}
  Hurray desiredValue exists in this view!
{{else}}
  Sorry, doesn't match...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Take a look at the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/biesior/dMS2d/ isn't there an easier way ? [if] statement inside the each is pseudo code of course

Comment: He would have to create a field for each value he want to check

Comment: Apparently there's no other way, this hinders a lot something which should be trivial... thx anyway